# Nautilus window buttons reappearing

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome, nautilus, budgie

I was trying out budgie desktop environment. After I installed it and removed it, I logged back in unity and my nautilus window now has close, maximize and minimize buttons re-appearing as below:

[image]

When I removed budgie, I used the purge command but I think there are some settings still remaining which has overridden the nautilus configuration.

I tried fixing it by reinstalling nautilus and nautilus-data packages. I also tried deleting the config present in ~/.config/nautilus.

Nothing has worked till now. Please help !

Comment: Well apt-get purge does not delete things in your home folder I would also try to narrow it down if it is a settings problem by logging into the guest session and see if it reoccurs there.

Comment: Did you restart the system ?

Answer (score 0):

The last thing that worked for me was downgrading the nautilus package to a previous version. I was inspired by the answer here: https://askubuntu.com/a/849499/275770